# PHP - Retrieving $_GET variable after submitting form and change URL

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have the following form I want to use to filter through products on my website:

```
<div class="top-filter-select-container">
    <form method="GET" action="" id="sort-filter-pick">
        <select class="selectpicker" id="sort-filter">
            <option value="popularity">Sort by Popularity</option>
            <option value="ratings">Sort by Ratings</option>
            <option value="newest">Sort by Newest</option>
            <option value="lowest">Sort by Lowest Price</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to reload my page when an option is selected using jQuery `form.submit()` and retrieve the selected option to be used for filtering with a SQL query. I would eventually want to use this value along with other filtering values for a more complex filtering.

```
$(function(){
    $('#sort-filter').on('change', function() {
        var action = $(this).val();
        $("#sort-filter-pick").attr("action", "?sort=" + action);
        this.form.submit();
    }); 
});
```

To test my code, I am just trying to `echo isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : null;`

The code works if I change `form method` to `POST` instead of `GET` but doesn't work with `GET`. On websites such as Amazon, the `GET` form method is used when applying filters from a select option but I also notice that the `?sort=`... is added to the page URL after the form is submitted, which is not the case for me if I use `GET`. I was wondering what would be the right approach to do the same thing.

Comment: value of GET does not pas in form body, they passes as url parameters

Comment: So how would I add my action to the URL? I guess that's my main question

Comment: do ajax request in onchange event or reload the page

Comment: since select box don't have name attribute that's wy get not working

Comment: Ryan, isn't this what `$("#sort-filter-pick").attr("action", "?sort=" + action);` is suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a "name" to your form-elements you don't need to manually add the sort-criteria with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="top-filter-select-container">
   <form method="GET" action="" id="sort-filter-pick">
       <select class="selectpicker" name="sort" id="sort-filter">
           <option value="popularity">Sort by Popularity</option>
           <option value="ratings">Sort by Ratings</option>
           <option value="newest">Sort by Newest</option>
           <option value="lowest">Sort by Lowest Price</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#sort-filter').on('change', function() {
        this.form.submit();
    }); 
});
```

Or you could just use `location.href = url` rather than posting the form.